# Getting undefined methods for validates_uniqueness_of in form object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class AfterSignUpForm < ApplicationController
  include ActiveModel::Model 
  validates_uniqueness_of :username
end
```

For the above form_object in rails, I don't know why I am getting the undefined method error, I have already included ActiveModel::Model

Answer (score 0):

You should write a model level validation in model class which is inherited by ActiveRecord:Base

Answer (score 0):

well, you're doing it in the controller, which is probably a bad idea. but to get to the actual issue, do you have a "username" in the controller? if not, that could be the issue (but again, i would not recommend having this mixin in the controller)